# WordPress submenu_page for Teams

Tags: wordpress

How would I go about creating a submenu page which I will then be able to add teams and within those teams I add players.

No need for code to be written out I would like just know what direction I should take to be able to achieve this!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you create pages in left sidebar present select with label Parent. Create page Teams. Than create pages for every team and select parent page as Teams for every single page.

One more way: create `post_type` `player` and `taxonomy` for them `team`. And create players and assign terms with team for each player. Create page, where you will print your teams and players. Like `post` and `post category` works in default wordpress.

Comment: Could I create page that lists all the teams, and once on that page click on the specific team I want which links me that specific team page with the custom post type and taxonomy method?

Comment: Yes, sure you can.